# DJANGO: how to make a view that check process of something

Tags: django, python-3.x

Many web apps which have a page that take more than 0.5ms to load have a intermediate status page. Such pages might have a spinning wheel or more useful for the user, state the current part of the process the server is at e.g.:

```
(page request)
(message 1) loading user preferences
(message 2) initializing user whatever
(message 3) getting content
(page loades)
```

How could one do this in Django? e.g. say there is a form and after submitting it may take a few minutes for the server to finish processing. How can I show the user where the server is at?

## Views

#### form page

```
def form_page(request):
    # stuff
    context = {'useful_data': useful_data}
    render(request, 'my_app/form_page.html', context)
```

#### handler page

```
def handler(request):
    # what goes here?
    render(request, 'my_app/form_page.html', context)
```

## HTML

#### form_page

```
{% load static %}    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'my_app/css/index.css' %}" />

<form action="{% url 'my_app:handler' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

#### handler

```
// Status goes / is updated here
??????
```

Comment: Perhaps you could achieve that in JS ?

Comment: @jpic could you teach / show me how?